# Vuetify v-bottom-sheet overlay suddenly appears without opened sheets

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, vuetify.js, overlay

Sometimes the v-bottom-sheet's dark overlay appears full screen, while at that time, NO sheets are open. It prevents users from interact with the page unless they reload page.

The bug is inconsistent, so it's hard to reproduce. One solution is to disable all overlay, but I still want to use it for my sheets. Any idea about this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that the **data variable** for displaying sheet is being set to **true** in some part of your code.You should check for all the **occurrences** of the sheet's data variable and you will definitely find where you are **setting it to true**.

```
this.sheet = !this.sheet;
//or
this.sheet = true;
```

Comment: I did check all the occurrences. The only things that is True are the initial data(automatically open).

Maybe when user start game and there is some lagging while updating database? I think it doesnt make sense because I have a conditional render, if the game is not started, then that component will not be rendered.

Comment: I intend to watch for game.started variable, if it's false, then always set the sheet False. How can I implement this?